# functional programming javascript chain filter operation defaults

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Is there a way to filter an array and if it returns no objects default to the default option in a single chain?

e.g.

```
[1,2,3]
    .filter(isDivisibleByTen)
    // otherwise return whatever
```

I could write it like so

```
const result [1,2,3].filter(isDivisibleByTen) 
result ? result [0]
```

Comment: Array converted to boolean is always `true`, therefore `result ? result : [0]` always returns `result`.

Comment: BTW it is not a functional programming. A functional would be this: `let array = [1,2,3]; array = filter(array, isDivisibleByTen); array = defaultify(array, 'defaultValue');`.

Comment: The empty list short circuits both functorial and monadic computations. So expecting a default element is somewhat against its algebraic structure, I guess. If you really need this, you can borrow the concept of `fromMaybe`: `fromNil = y => xs => xs[0] || y`, when accessing the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1. Without side effects.

Maybe [reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) is the only Array method that provides the array and can return an arbitrary value so you can use it:

```
[1,2,3]
    .filter(isDivisibleByTen)
    .reduce((_1, _2, _3, array) => array, 'defaultValue');
```

This solution is a bit processor-time-wasting (loops over the array without a benefit), but it can be combined with any chain easily.

#### Solution 2. The elegant one.

You can add a custom method to the Array prototype to make it available in a chain:

```
Array.prototype.filledOrDefault = function(defaultValue) {
    return this.length ? this : defaultValue;
}

[1,2,3]
    .filter(isDivisibleByTen)
    .filledOrDefault('defaultValue');
```

This solution is not recommended because it modifies a global value (`Array`) which is used by other scripts on a page.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think you are looking for in one line, but if a result is false, filter() will return nothing. In Demo 1 `filter()` is used. In Demo 2 `map()` is used with a return of an arbitrary value of `"default"` as the alternate return.

---

### Demo 1

---

```js
console.log([1, 21, 30].filter(a => a % 10 === 0));
```

---

### Demo 2

---

```js
console.log([1,21,30].map(a => a % 10 === 0 ? a : 'default'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `reduce()`. This allows you to pass an initial value (the default return value) and then add values to the return array if they pass the test. So if no values pass the test, the function will return the default value.

```js
console.log([1,21,30].reduce((t, v) => { return v % 10 === 0 ? (t = 'default' ? [v] : t.concat(v)) : t; }, 'default'))
```

```js
    console.log([1,21,35].reduce((t, v) => { return v % 10 === 0 ? (t = 'default' ? [v] : t.concat(v)) : t; }, 'default'))
```

Comment: From my understanding, if there's only one item, then it should return that item, not as an array. E.g. 30 instead of [30] in your example

Comment: @AnilRedshift that doesn't agree with OPs original solution of using `filter()` which will return a single element array if there is only one item which matches.

Answer (score 0):

I'll add a more verbose option here. This solution makes use of 3 pure functions, and then combines it in a pipeline. This is pretty typical of functional programming, and has the side benefit of being able to test the functions in isolation to make sure they do exactly what you want.

(As a sidebar other languages such as elixir make the chaining more syntactically pleasing, but I digress)

```js
const defaultValue = "foobar";

const isDivisibleBy10 = n => n % 10 === 0;

const enforceDefault = numbers => numbers.length ? numbers : [defaultValue];

const unpackSingleton = numbers => numbers.length === 1 ? numbers[0] : numbers;


const pipeline = numbers =>
  unpackSingleton(
    enforceDefault(
      numbers.filter(isDivisibleBy10)
    )
  )

console.log(pipeline([2])); // no matches so returns default
console.log(pipeline([20])) // one match so returns the item

console.log(pipeline([1, 20, 10, 3])) // general case
```

Comment: `enforceDefault(numbers.filter(isDivisibleBy10))` is not a chain. `numbers.filter(isDivisibleBy10).enforceDefault()` would be a chain.